# Is there a social networking protocol

Tags: protocols, social-networking

Social networking is great, but there is something fundamentally wrong with the way social networking is implemented today in most popular services. I'll put it in this example: Imagine that there is no SMTP, and consequently, it is globally assumed and accepted that you can only send email to addresses on the same domain. The result would be the emergence of a single email service, let's call it emailbook.com, which we all have to subscribe to, if we really want to communicate with the world.
This is what's happening with social networking today. You HAVE to use the same service your fiends/colleagues are using to talk to them.
I would like to be able to put up my own social site, invite my friends who trust me, share amongst us, but still be able to share with the world at large.
What are the chances of this scenario happening in the future? What does it take?

Comment: Facebook has just launched a new API, which... with the size of facebook just might be called the new standard ;)

Comment: [Distributed Social Networking Protocol](http://www.complang.org/dsnp/)

Comment: It's sad to note how few years later there is still nothing (and almost all anwers point now to dead links)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There sure is, and not just one! The future you wanted is now here.

By the time of the question, back in the end of 2010, [OStatus](https://ostatus.github.io/spec/OStatus%201.0%20Draft%202.html) had already existed for half a year, and the year before that there was OpenMicroBlogging (OMB), and at about the same time as OMB, the XMPP [XEP 0277](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0277.html).

Since then several other protocols have popped up, such as [diaspora*](https://diaspora.github.io/diaspora_federation/) just half a year later, and later some smaller players like Friendica's DFRN and HubZilla's Zot.

OStatus never left draft status, but the big buzz[0] these days is about [ActivityPub](https://activitypub.rocks/), which is a W3C recommendation since [January 2018](https://www.w3.org/blog/news/archives/6785) and came out of the Social WG mentioned by @keithjgrant in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41642303). There is a [multitude of implementations](https://fediverse.party/)[1], finding their niches with different use cases like microblogging, blogging, link sharing, picture sharing, video sharing and audio sharing.

There is also the collection of blog-oriented protocols described on https://indieweb.org/.

[0] [pun intended](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Buzz)

[1] Diaspora and GNU Social, although shown at fediverse.party, do not implement ActivityPub. The other applications shown do. There are several other applications not shown there, such as FunkWhale, Plume, WriteFreely, Prismo ... There is no terse and complete overview of all of them, but several are listed at https://switching.social/ and https://wedistribute.org/ publishes news and interviews related to all of them.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few.  One Social Web uses XMPP which is open and decentralized like SMTP.
Check it out.

http://onesocialweb.org/

Comment: also http://ostatus.org/specification

Answer (score 1):

I absolutely agree. The good news is, yes, things are happening. Even better, they are happening in the W3C, which means open standards.

The W3C now has a [Social Web working group](https://www.w3.org/wiki/Socialwg/DocumentStatus). They are actively working on a handful of standards. The biggest of these seems to be the [Social Web Protocol](https://www.w3.org/TR/social-web-protocols/).

Today, they also posted the W3C Recommended spec for [Webmention](https://www.w3.org/TR/webmention/), which is sort of an improved version of the old pingbacks that used to be used on blogs, this time built on HTTP. It allows a post to notify another page on the web when it references it. There are already a number of libraries and services that [implement this today](https://indieweb.org/Webmention#Services).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take a look at http://code.google.com/apis/opensocial/. It is a spec developed by google and other social networking players. It supports interoperability and much more.

OpenSocial is currently being developed by a broad set of members of the web community. The ultimate goal is for any social website to be able to implement the API and host 3rd party social applications. There are many websites that support OpenSocial, including hi5, LinkedIn, MySpace, Netlog, Ning, orkut, and Yahoo!

Comment: @Original Poster - My bad! You asked about protocol.. I gone into specifications.. Sorry!!